# Selenium. Как открыть ссылку на новой вкладке браузера и перейти на эту вкладку?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Код открывает ссылку на новой вкладке

Привожу фрагмент кода

```
et = Browser.FindElement(By.LinkText("Книги"));
et.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Return);
```

**ВОПРОС**

Как сделать, чтобы при открытии ссылки в новой вкладке программа ещё и переходила на эту вкладку?

Comment: Не подскажу, как в шарпе это апи реализовано, но в java необходимо у WebDriver забрать объект типа TargetLocator (driver.switchTo()) и у него вызвать метод window(String nameOrHandle) куда передать имя или handle вкладки/окна

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://ru.stackoverflow.com/");

var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("nav-badges"));

Actions newTab = new Actions(driver);
newTab
    .KeyDown(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control)
    .KeyDown(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Shift)
    .Click(element).KeyUp(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control).KeyUp(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Shift)
    .Build()
    .Perform();

//если всего будет две вкладки, то перейти на новую можно так:
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не могли бы вы подсказать как исправить ошибку: "The type or namespace name 'Actions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". При этом Actions подчёркнуто красным

Comment: добавьте пространство имен `using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Есть ещё небольшой вопрос:  как сделать. чтобы Браузер опять переключился на исходную вкладку с Url("http://ru.stackoverflow.com/")? Обращаю внимание, именно Браузер, а не код. Т.е. имитация нажатия Ctrl+Page Up (Ctrl+Page Down)