# Как правильно переключаться между вкладками Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

У меня тупо загружает новую страницу в этой же вкладке необходимо решение на Python

```
import get_number as getnum
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
one = browser.get("https://google.com")
body = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
two = browser.get("http://mail.ru") <--- Он все равно открывает во вкладке 0
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[0])<--- И не переключается. Ибо некуда
```

И как потом между ними переключаться

Comment: Так там не на Питоне? Что за Var

Comment: виноват, это был С#... и тем не менее, не пробовали найти ответ поиском?

Comment: Это уже после поисков

Comment: попробуте browser.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't'), а затем browser.get("http://mail.ru"), переключиться можно driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

Comment: Я так и пробую. Добавил ваш вариант. Он открывает в той же вкладке что и гуглу

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17558909/5909792 ?

Comment: browser.send_keys ошибку выдает нет у броузера атрибута сенд кейс

Comment: Там больше для Явы. А Питоновский код у меня один в один с ихним. Но он открывает в той же вкладке

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Selenium. Как открыть ссылку на новой вкладке браузера и перейти на эту вкладку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/586498/selenium-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d1%83)

Comment: Это на C#. Смотрел я этот вопрос. Даже пытался применить к Питону. Совсем не то это. Методы не аналогичны с Питоном